# how to re-open or close SQLitedatabase?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have gone through many pages for the same problem but i still cant find an solution     for this !!

I'm getting error "attempt to re-open an already closed objectSQLiteDatabase".

```
public List getData(){
List list = new ArrayList();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table",null );
int i = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY1);
int ii = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY2);
int iii = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY3);
int inum = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY4); 

cursor.moveToFirst();
  while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){

String student = cursor.getString(inum) + "\t" +cursor.getString(i) +"\t" +cursor.getString(ii) + "\t" +cursor.getString(iii);

     list.add(student); 
         cursor.moveToPrevious();   
        }
    }


      public List getInfo()


 {

List list = new ArrayList();
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table where name = ?",new string[]{"android"} );
int i = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY1);
int ii = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY2);
int iii = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY3);
int inum = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY4); 

cursor.moveToFirst();
  while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){

String student = cursor.getString(inum) + "\t" +cursor.getString(i) +"\t" +cursor.getString(ii) + "\t" +cursor.getString(iii);

     list.add(student); 
         cursor.moveToPrevious();   
        }
```

Im getting this values as list and putting it in list

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
 List val = info.getData();
 List val1 - info.getInfo();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new      ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,val);
ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new       ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,val1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
info.close()
```

Comment: Where do you create `db` and close it?

Comment: Please, indent (format) your code! I'm getting headaches!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all where are you creating database?

You should use a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper

eg:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
     //here you create your database and tables
}
```

To open/close database

```
// Database Fields
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

More info/example here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html